# SwiftUI Local Notification Delegate

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications, iso, localnotification

I made two classes to manage local notifications, to get more notification functionality I used local notification delegation, but it's doesn't work (the delegation functions) may be because I didn't set it correctly, if there is any way to fix this issue please share it with me.

Notification Manager

```
internal final class LocalNotificationManager: ObservableObject {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    @Published var authorizationState: UNAuthorizationStatus?
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    func reloadAuthorizationState() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.authorizationState = settings.authorizationStatus
            }
        }
    }
    
    func requestAuthorization() {
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
               // Do something if user allowing notifications
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authorizationState = .authorized
                }
            } else if !granted {
                // Do something if user do not allow the notifications
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authorizationState = .denied
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                // Show some message
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func schedulNotification(for taskModel: TaskModel) {
        
        // Set Delegation
        let delegate = LocalNotificationDelegate()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = delegate
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.interruptionLevel = .timeSensitive
        content.title = ""
        content.body = taskModel.text
        content.subtitle = "\(taskModel.priority != .none ? "\(taskModel.priority.rawValue) Priority" : "")"
        content.categoryIdentifier = "Task Actions" // Same Identifier in registerCategories()
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        let taskIdentifier = taskModel.id.uuidString
            
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        registerCategories(for: taskModel)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        
    }
    
    private func registerCategories(for taskModel: TaskModel) {
        let markAsCompleted = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "MARK_AS_COMPLETED", title: "Mark as Completed", icon: UNNotificationActionIcon(systemImageName: "checkmark.circle"))
        let remindMeInAnHour = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "REMIND_ME_IN_AN_HOUR", title: "Remind Me in an Hour", icon: UNNotificationActionIcon(systemImageName: "clock"))
        let remindMeTomorrow = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "REMIND_ME_TOMORROW", title: "Remind Me Tomorrow", icon: UNNotificationActionIcon(systemImageName: "calendar"))
        
        let placeholder = "Task"
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "Task Actions", actions: [markAsCompleted, remindMeInAnHour, remindMeTomorrow], intentIdentifiers: [], hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: placeholder) // // Same Identifier in schedulNotification()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    }
```

Notification Delegat

```
internal final class LocalNotificationDelegate: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification,
       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
       completionHandler(.banner)
     }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        switch response.actionIdentifier {
            
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            // the user tapped to unlock
            print("User Tapped to Unlock the App")
            
        case "MARK_AS_COMPLETED":
            print("MARK_AS_COMPLETED")
            break
        case "REMIND_ME_IN_AN_HOUR":
            print("REMIND_ME_IN_AN_HOUR")
            break
        case "REMIND_ME_TOMORROW":
            print("REMIND_ME_TOMORROW")
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790996/daily-local-notifications-are-not-working/68803049#68803049

Comment: Thank you "lorem ipsum" and "lukaskasa", both of you lead me to the same solving of the problem and that fix the issue.