# UNNotificationRequest only triggers once after device reboot

Tags: xcode, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification

Local Notification only triggers once after device reboot. when i close and reopen the app it won't trigger even though i see it enters the function send() every time i run the app.

i have the trigger set to nil so it will trigger Imm . any ideas what am i getting wrong ?

Thank you so much
O.K

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications


 @main
struct ozApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().onAppear {   send()  }
            
        }
    }
    
    func send(){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
            if success {
                print("All set!")
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
         
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Message"
        content.subtitle = "999"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid , content: content, trigger: nil)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is likely triggering but app "throws it away" because you aren't telling it what to do when the app is in the foreground via the delegate

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675639/schedule-local-notification-every-n-days-timezone-safe/68039675#68039675) is a more complicated trigger but you will see the basics applied.